# FileShare ReadWrite not working (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, file, fileshare

I'm using a hex-editor control for C#, the source code and binary files can be found [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox)

One problem when using it was that if a file was loaded in the hex-editor and another program, the other program can't save the file, because it's already being used by another process.

So I asked the author of the control who told me to set the FileShare argument in the File.Open method in the FileByteProvider and DynamicFileByteProvider class to ReadWrite (it was originally only Read) would fix it. So I did that, but it still didn't work (same error). Setting it to Write only also didn't work, but setting it to Read only and None both work. The files have the same problem in any program, for example Notepad. They aren't set to ReadOnly or anything, so I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 9):

The problem might be with the other program - if it's trying to open the file for exclusive access (with no sharing), it doesn't matter how *your* program has opened the file - it's going to fail.

---

Whenever a program tries to open a file, you specify a FileAccess and FileShare parameter (or defaults are taken if they're not explicitly passed).

What Windows then has to do is check all existing open file handles, and determine whether they're compatible. So it compares your FileAccess parameter against everyone else's FileShare parameters - *are you allowed to do what everyone else has said they're happy for others to do?* And then it performs the opposite check - does your FileShare parameter match up with their FileAccess parameters? - *are they doing things that you're happy for them to be doing?* Only if both checks pass can your particular open request be approved.

You can use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to actually watch the Win32 calls being issued to [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what each process is actually doing.

---

Notepad can open a file that's been shared for Read/Write, but it can't write back to the file. Sample program:

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Bar.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            fs.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc"),0,3);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close(); //<-- Breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Set the given breakpoint, run the program. When it hits the breakpoint, open Notepad, and use it to open C:\Bar.txt. Everything is fine. Add more text to the file and hit save. You'll get an error message.

Comment: Notepad is an example of a program that allows ReadWrite I think. I can open a file in notepad and another program and make changes in both without any problems. But with this hex-editor, I can't and the same happens for a few other programs (they work fine). This is what makes me think it's a problem with the hex-editor.

Comment: I just read your edited post. I'm interesting in knowing why Notepad can open a file that's been shared for Read/Write, but can't write back to the file? Also, even if you're right in this sense, I'm 100% sure it's still a problem with the hex-editor because files that are opened with that program and another program can work with the same file fine. It makes me think File Share is set to Read/Write in that program too. But yeah I am interesting in knowing more about your first statement.

Comment: @Iceyoshi - because when notepad tries to write back to the file, it's changing it's access (or reopening the file) and specifying `FileShare.None` or `FileShare.Read` (well, actually the Win32 equivalents, it's not .Net so far as I'm aware) - and that's not compatible with my program's `FileAccess.ReadWrite`

Answer (score 0):

1. Change to ReadWrite.
2. Recompile.
3. Try opening a file that you haven't tried opening yet and check if the problem appears.

Possibly, you weren't closing the file appropriately so it remained open even after you closed your application (with previous permissions set to Read)

Comment: What do you mean by 'appropriately' here? I've tried it with many different files and the problem appears to be there in all of them.

Comment: By closing appropriately I meant closing at all :) I don't have time to analyze your code, so it was my assumption that the file isn't closed at all.