# C#: How to read a file that's in use by another process

Tags: c#, file

There is one text file in hard drive which continuously writing by some application `XYZ`.

Now, from application `ABC`, I am trying to read the file, but I am getting error,

`the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Note - I don't have control over `XYZ` application, still is there any way to read the file from application `ABC`?

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(File.FullName)
```

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough? The other process has that file locked, so nobody can read it or modify it.

Comment: then is there any solution

Comment: This means the other application is currently accessing the file. You have to close the stream to the file from the other app first.

Comment: If you want to find out which process is locking the file, consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net) post.

Comment: Other application `XYZ`, we don't have any control. Is there any other way that I can do something from application 'ABC`

Comment: Afraid not - if the other process has opened the file in non-sharing mode, you simply won't be able to open it in any other process.

Comment: can we check this ? `if the other process has opened the file in non-sharing mode`

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader

Comment: You might want to see if you can successfully open the file using `System.IO.File.Open` with the various sharing flags (e.g. `System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite`). But if the other application is opening it exclusively, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Try to read file with `using (var fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))`

Comment: (1) The FileShare setting applies to subsequent openings of the file, so it is the other process that must set it correctly. (2) `File.ReadAllBytes()` already opens the file in Read mode. If it doesn't work with `File.ReadAllBytes()` then unfortunately it won't work with `new FileStream()` either, no matter what parameters you use.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's not true. ReadAllBytes specifies `FileShare.Read`. If file is already opened with `FileAccess.Write` or ReadWrite - `ReadAllBytes` will fail to read it. However, if you specify `FileShare.ReadWrite` - you will be able to read that file if another party specified compatible share mode (`FileShare.Read` or `ReadWrite`).

Comment: Thanks @Evk, You'r solution is working

Comment: Dear All, why so many down vote? May be my question is duplicate, but not incorrect

Comment: @Evk That's strange - see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689958/106159)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Seems to confirm my point. "And then it performs the opposite check - does your FileShare parameter match up with their FileAccess parameters?" FileShare in case of ReadAllBytes is FileShare.Read. It is not compatible with any FileAccess which includes Write. So, ReadAllBytes is not happy when any other process (not future, but already existing too) writes to the file. But FileShare.ReadWrite is compatible with FileAccess.Write. So, both FileShare and FileAccess should be compatible with those of other already existing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you can also confirm with experiment. Start thread and create filestream with `FileAccess.Write` and `FileShare.ReadWrite` and slowly write something in it. Then from main thread try to read it with ReadAllBytes - that will fail. Then try to read with FileShare.ReadWrite - that will work.

Comment: @Evk OK, that makes sense. (I was thinking along the lines that asking for "Read sharing" access was less restrictive than asking for "ReadWrite", but it's actually the other way around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the file in read mode so that you will not get this error.
Try this solution
[How do I open an already opened file with a .net StreamReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader)